# missing semi-colon before shared pointer type

Tags: c++

I am desperate to struggle this trivial but heartache issue
I have a class

```
///A.h
class A
{
   //declare something
};
///A.cpp
//implement that something of A
```

then another class

```
///B.h
class A;
class B
{
private:
   A_PTR aptr; //Missing ';' before aptr
public:
   A_PTR getA();
};
///B.cpp
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_PTR;
//implement all B's methods
```

Why do I get an error message at A_PTR as declaring aptr in class B ?

Comment: You're using `A_PTR` before you've declared it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `A_PTR` is not yet defined. You need to move the definition above the first point you use it:

```
///B.h
class A;
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_PTR;
class B
{
private:
   A_PTR aptr;
public:
   A_PTR getA();
};
```

Comment: @Borgleader, no it doesn't. Only the constructors taking ownership of a pointer need the full declaration (so they can create a type-erased deleter for the type).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well I'm sure I got an error like that before... strange (removing my comment)

Comment: I think you'd only need the definition if you dereference the shared pointer in the header. The shared pointer doesn't need to know the size of the object.

Comment: Do you define any methods which use `A` in your header?

Comment: Actually I have a lot of headers. I don't understand what you mean by methods that use A in the header. No implementation of B that uses A is done in the header. They are all in cpp, except some operators I code them inline

Comment: If any of the operators you define inline return or take an `A` or dereference the shared pointer then you need a complete type.

Comment: Could you edit your post and give me a sample ? Especially when my code is interdependent on each other (this has that and that has this)

Comment: @user3305259 you'd probably be better off pasting your header into pastepin or similar so I can look at it.